# Simplifying system block diagram

Tags: control-theory

Does my simplifying look correct? - Updated from the 4th image (Final answer has not been reduced).

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have a minus sign wrong in the 4th image. And I am not sure what steps you took to get to the 5th image but it look very wrong.

Comment: I'll have another look at the 5th step, but where is the wrong minus sign in the the 4th step?

Comment: Top left, within the brackets after $H_1$.

Comment: The $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{G_1}}$ was going into a negative summing junction before it was combined with the other unity gain leg and $H_1$

Comment: But that unity gain is also going into negative summing junction.

Comment: So it should be $H_1\left( -1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{G_1}}\right)$ going into a positive summing junction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65458/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-stuart).